# Svelte Testing Library doesn't update component state on input value change

Tags: testing, frontend, state, svelte

I'm tring to test a component using svelte testing library.

The component has an input tag, whose value is bound (using `bind:`) to a state variable, and that state variable dictates the text of a title.

So when you change the value of the input tag, it changes the text in the title.

I set up a unit test with svelte testing library, and use `fireEvent` to change the value of the input tag, but upon asserting the text in the title, it is not changed. It is as if the input tag value changes, but the svelte component state does not update.

Why does the state not change and the title not update? Is there something extra I have to do to get it to update?

Codesandbox repro (run test cases to see problem): https://codesandbox.io/s/xnxjo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things:

1. When you use `bind:value` on an input component in Svelte, Svelte attaches an `input` event listener to know when to update the value. Firing a change event will update the value, but will not trigger the event listener. So, use `fireEvent.input` instead of `fireEvent.change`.
2. Just because the event has fired doesn't mean the component state has updated. You can wrap `fireEvent` with [act](https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/api#act-async) to ensure the component updates before asserting anything.

Updated test:

```js
it("should write in input (variant)", async () => {
  const app = render(App);
  const input = app.getByLabelText("textbox");

  await act(() => fireEvent.input(input, { target: { value: "test" } }));

  expect(input.value).toBe("test");
  expect(app.container.querySelector("h1").textContent).toBe("test");
});
```

Comment: thanks, this works! Although I ended up using the `userEvent` library instead 

Comment: thanks you saved my two last days. One thing : it wasn't necessary for me to wrap fireEvent (even with my tests that was sending an ajax request).
I made the reverse move that @Takin1n1 : we're using $app/env that needs ESM to compile for jest. And we didn't achieve to make ESM/jest work with userEvent.

Comment: For me it was about the act(), now also this works for me:  

`await act(() => userEvent.click(screen.getByText('text')));`